# GWTP Boilerplate Generation - Eclipse Annotation Processing

Tags: eclipse, maven, annotations, boilerplate, gwtp

Has anyone had success following the Eclipse Annotation Processing directions for GWTP [Boilerplate Generation](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/tools/Boilerplate-Generation.html)?  I followed the directions for Eclipse Annotation Processing, but cannot import the GWTP annotation package.

I'd appreciate any insight on either Eclipse Annotation Processing, or the alternative Maven Configuration setup that is mentioned also.

These are the directions from GWTP [Boilerplate Generation](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/tools/Boilerplate-Generation.html) (bottom of page):

> Eclipse Annotation Processing
>
> In Eclipse, the annotation processor kicks in as soon as you save the file you're working on and incrementally
>   changes only the required files. Another method exists by using the Eclipse lifecycle mapping. If the lifecycle
>   mapping is used, the annotation processor doesn't have to be setup. Find out more in the Maven Configuration on
>   how to setup the annotation processing with out touching eclipse properties.
>
> To enable GWTP annotation processing in eclipse:
>
> - Open the properties for your project
> - Ticking all the boxes on the Annotation Processing page.
>     Ticking all the boxes on the Annotation Processing page.
> - Add the GWTP jar to the factory path.
>     Add the GWTP jar to the factory path.

Answer (score 0):

In maven you can try this:

1) Import gwtp processors

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
<artifactId>gwtp-processors</artifactId>
<version>${gwtplatform.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2) use next plugins

```
<!-- Run annotation processors on src/home/java sources -->
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
                        <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```